# Best dataload from Google storage to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-storage

Which is best service in gcp to load data from gcs to Bigquery in incremental model .

Which can be automated throught Terraform

That can be handle by Terraform.

snowflake data to bigquery datasets and need your suggestions

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#sql

You could setup a BQ SQL job and trigger it with a cron event.